# Adding Numbers in C#

Tags: c#, addition

I currently have this, but it keeps resulting in the number say I put in 5 it will make it 51 instead of the result I want of 6. Can anyone help me?

```
int number;
int outcome;

number = int.Parse(numberInputTextBox.Text);

outcomeLabel.Text = number + 1 .ToString();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
number = int.Parse(numberInputTextBox.Text);
outcomeLabel.Text = (number + 1).ToString();
```

You forgot to add ( ). Your sample was:

```
1) take 1 and convert to string
2) add number and string
```

in point 2) the number was casted to string before adding to second string. That's why you got string concatenation "5"+"1"="51" instead of integer sum 5+1=6

Answer (score 1):

`1.ToString()` will return a string, which you are then adding the string "5" to, as C# will
implicitly cast the number `5` to the string `"5"` when trying to add it to a string.

You need to first add one, then convert to a string, giving something like this:

```
outcomeLabel.Text = (number + 1).ToString();
```

or

```
int newNumber = number + 1;
outcomeLabel.Text = newNumber.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add parentheses...

```
number = int.Parse(numberInputTextBox.Text);

outcomeLabel.Text = (number + 1).ToString();
```